# rightMouseDown: not called in NSControl subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have an `NSControl` subclass (which is configured as a layer-hosting view, although I doubt that's relevant). I've been attempting to write the code to get and display a context menu. However, neither `menuForEvent:` or `rightMouseDown:` are being called. Any idea what could be causing that? Other mouse events work correctly.

As an aside, I'm not sure if I have to call `menuForEvent:` myself, but the docs made it sound like I don't, which is why I tried overriding it first. Regardless, I should at least expect `rightMouseDown:` to be called…

Related: it appears that AppKit doesn't recognize Ctrl+Click as a right mouse click. Presumably I have to check for this condition in `mouseDown:` and call `rightMouseDown:` manually. But given the weirdness I'm seeing, is there some other way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the `-(NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint` method in your subclass? It could be that the mouse event is being picked up by another element in your view and that would prevent `menuForEvent` being called.

You are correct in thinking that menuForEvent should be called automatically.

Comment: Turns out I was an idiot; I had forgotten that the layer was actually living inside a subview (so that I could arrange a scroller alongside the layer) I subclassed my layer-hosting view and had it forward the `rightMouseDown:` message to `nextResponder`. After that, `menuForEvent:` and everything else started working as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check its return value from `mouseDownCanMoveWindow`. The documentation isn't terribly clear, but implies that if this method returns `YES`, the view (control) won't get the mouse-down event.

If that turns out to be your problem, create a subclass of the control's class (if it's not already a subclass) and implement that method to return `NO`.